# I run a java programm as a windows service, and it can't find paths on the system

Tags: java, windows, windows-services

Is it possible that as a windows service, java can not modify files on the system?

Example: I create a directory under C:\Users\user\Documents, if i run the application as a Jar it works, but as soon as i run it as a windows service it can not find the path.

Any solutions?

Comment: Have made sure that your service runs under that account? Those user files will most likely be protected otherwise.

Comment: Yes i run it as logged in user

Comment: Are you using `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file`? If using the former, that is deprecated (not `@Deprecated`, deprecated), switch it. Because the latter gives better errors. Then, are you getting a `java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException`? It's not lying to you. The fix isn't in programming, it's in windows settings. Either way I don't think this question is right for SO.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.